# Rotate a line using the mouse in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, rotation, line

given the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class DragRotation extends JPanel {
Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(100,75,200,160);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2.draw(rect);
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2.draw(at.createTransformedShape(rect));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DragRotation test = new DragRotation();
    test.addMouseListener(test.rotator);
    test.addMouseMotionListener(test.rotator);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(test);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

private MouseInputAdapter rotator  = new MouseInputAdapter() {
    Point2D.Double center = new Point2D.Double();
    double thetaStart = 0;
    double thetaEnd = 0;
    boolean rotating = false;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        Shape shape = at.createTransformedShape(rect);
        if(shape.contains(p)) {
            Rectangle r = shape.getBounds();
            center.x = r.getCenterX();
            center.y = r.getCenterY();
            double dy = p.y - center.y;
            double dx = p.x - center.x;
            thetaStart = Math.atan2(dy, dx) - thetaEnd;
            System.out.printf("press thetaStart = %.1f%n",
                               Math.toDegrees(thetaStart));
            rotating = true;
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        rotating = false;
        double dy = e.getY() - center.y;
        double dx = e.getX() - center.x;
        thetaEnd = Math.atan2(dy, dx) - thetaStart;
        System.out.printf("release thetaEnd = %.1f%n",
                           Math.toDegrees(thetaEnd));
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if(rotating) {
            double dy = e.getY() - center.y;
            double dx = e.getX() - center.x;
            double theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            at.setToRotation(theta - thetaStart, center.x, center.y);
            repaint();
        }
    }
};
}
```

If i change the line: Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(100,75,200,160);
to Line2D.Double rect = new Line2D.Double(100,75,200,160); in order to create a 2D line.
After that how should i modify the code,so that it is able to get the coordinates of the mouse over the line and make the whole code work for rotation of the line.

Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

For determine rotation you use [`shape.contains(p)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#contains%28java.awt.geom.Point2D%29) it's work for Rectangle, but it doesn't work for a line, because I think it is really hard to point inside a Line.

You need to specify some area for rotation flag of a line, somthing like next :

```
if(rect.x1 < p.x && rect.x2 > p.x 
        && rect.y1 < p.y && rect.y2 > p.y){
}
```

instead of

```
if(shape.contains(p)) {
}
```

in your `mousePressed()` method.

Comment: Yeah,
came up with similar solution.Thanks!